# Rails/Heroku - calling ruby class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a method in a class (Scraper.rb) that saves some data to the app's database. On my dev environment I just call it through the command line. How can I call it on an app that's hosted on Heroku?

Comment: If you want to save any primary data to your data base I suggest you to do it with seed file, but if you want to run the method from console as your dev env. you can run command "heroku run console" or "heroku run rauls c"

Comment: Well that was simple, thanks Garurav. This data changes somewhat frequently so I don't think I'll seed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run the method from heroku console as your dev env. you can run command

> **heroku run console**

or

> **heroku run rails c**

Answer (score 0):

This would normally do the trick in my app:

> heroku run rails runner Scrapper.rb -e production

Obviously my app is in production in heroku so you apply the environment you want.